# Iomega Home Media hard drive shows empty directories after data loss

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have an Iomega Home Media Network Hard Drive, 1TB. After a 220V blackout we had during the night and due to the cold weather, I can't access the data on the drive.

The shares (both built-in and created by me) are there, the security works, but when trying to access the data, I just get my directory tree **empty** at any level.

I pulled the drive and mounted it via USB to a PC running Ubuntu. It mounts both partitions (boot ext3 and data xfs) and the result is the same: On the xfs partition I get just the directory tree, but it's empty!

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same problem.  Cold weather, sudden loss of power to the Iomega drive and now...no data.

Same as you - folders are OK, but no data at all.  Pretty shocking stuff!!

I got hold of Iomega support who said it was probably a firmware issue, but I have the latest firmware so they couldn't help me other than replace the drive.

I managed to rescue my data using Data Rescue 3.1 on a Mac, and the drive works again after formatting it, but overall, this is just unacceptable from Iomega!!

My advice - Don't buy Iomega ever again!  And use a good data recovery tool to get your data back - it is still on the drive, but the firmware has done something mental to the drive tables.